# How do I put pre-populate a value of a form field? When the page loads, the text is already there inputted

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, uri

lets say
var name = "test";

Have tried
$('#form-text').text(name); and $('#form-text').val(name);

No matter what happens, the name is not being inputted and the form field is still empty.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the input to be pre-populated you can do it in the following ways.

If the value is static/constant. You can just add `value` attribute and specify the default name you want to pre-populate.

```
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="text" id="name" value="Jane">
  <input type="email" id="email">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The above code will set the `#name` input to have a value 'Jane'.

If you don't know the value then you need to set it on load.
In your JS code, find the element and set the value attribute.

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("name").value = "John Doe";
};
```

The above code will set the `#name` input to have a value 'John Doe'.